# react icon component is not centered in the li

Tags: html, css, reactjs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOyFn.png
I am creating a blog post using react-icons, but the icon component is not centered in the li item. I have no idea where is the mistake I made in my css. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Blog.css';

import { IoLogoFacebook, IoLogoTwitter, IoLogoInstagram, IoLogoYoutube } from "react-icons/io";

const Blog = () => {
return (
<div className="blog-card">
  <div className="meta">
    <div className="photo"></div>
      <ul className="details">
        <li className="author"><a href="#">John Doe</a></li>
        <li className="date">
           <IoLogoFacebook />
              Aug. 24, 2020
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
)
```

Here is css

```
.blog-card .details,
.blog-card .details ul {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.blog-card .details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  margin: auto;
  transition: left 0.2s;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.blog-card .details ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Whether this is your expectation? https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-hooks-6ewyr

Comment: No really. I've added an image to show the problem. If the icon move down a little bit, it would be better. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this on your date class style

```
.date {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
}
```

I have tested it on @Maniraj's sandbox : [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-currying-7fl9c?file=/src/App.js)